# Rails is not using my parameters to send data back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an angular app running on rails and im trying to get data from my rails backend with parameters and it always just returns all votes. I think my problem is on my backend.

It is always calling the index action but it doesnt use the parameters, someone please help me get this to work

Here is the server output

```
Started GET "/api/v1/votes.json?votable_id=129&votable_type=Post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-28 13:16:51 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::VotesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"votable_id"=>"129", "votable_type"=>"Post"}
  Vote Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes"   ORDER BY id DESC
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Here is my controller

```
  module Api
    module V1
     class VotesController < ApplicationController
       respond_to :json

       def index
         respond_with(Vote.all.order("id DESC"))
       end

       def show
         respond_with(Vote.find(params[:id]))
       end

       def create
         @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)
         @vote.save
         respond_with @vote, location: ""
       end

       def update 
         @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
         @vote.update(vote_params)
         respond_with @vote, location: ""
       end

       def destroy
         respond_with Vote.destroy(params[:id])
       end

     private
       def vote_params
         params.require(:vote).permit(:vote, :votable_id, :    votable_type, :user_id)
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a GET request to the votes controller, which (without an id as part of the request path) will call the index action, as outlined in `config/routes.rb`. If you want votes to be displayed selectively from index, you'll have to work selectively with params in your index action.

```
def index
  @votes = Vote.where('votable_id IN (?)', params[:votable_id])
               .where('votable_type = ?', params[:votable_type])
               .order('id DESC')
  respond_with(@votes)
end
```